# Use .htaccess to redirect to directory URL but show the URL as if in root

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, reference

I currently have a CRUD that has the following file structure:

[image]

The *index.php* file redirects to the *add-product.php*, *delete.php* and other files. The problem is, the URL looks like: *myapp.com/resources/views/add-product* but I want it to look like *myapp.com/add-product*. I found other StackOverflow posts similar to this, but it redirects to the desired link, instead of redirecting to the correct link but showing the desired one, and because of that the site doesn't work ("The requested URL was not found on this server"). The *.htaccess* file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^resources/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

I'm also using the file to be able to remove the *.php* from the URLs. The last line is the one handling the wrong redirection. How can I go about this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use it like this:

```sh
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myapp/

# external redirect to remove /resources/views/ from URLs
RewriteRule ^resources/views/(.+)\.php$ $1 [L,NC,R=302]

# internal rewrite to add /resources/views/ and .php to show content
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myapp/resources/views/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ resources/views/$1.php [END]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: I'm getting `The requested URL was not found on this server.` with this friend

Comment: What URL is shown in browser when this error occurs?

Comment: I see it was a failure from my part. It shows `https://localhost/add-product` when it should show `https://localhost/myapp/add-product` because I'm using XAMPP for local deployment while I'm still developing. It probably will work when fully deployed, but for now how should I use the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Check updated answer. In production change `RewriteBase /myapp/` to `RewriteBase /`

Comment: It's providing the correct link now, but I'm still getting `The requested URL was not found on this server.`

Comment: Check updated answer again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243335/discussion-between-gabriel-tkacz-and-anubhava).

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your help, it's working *ALMOST* perfectly. It's redirecting to the correct pages while showing the desired URL, but the POST information that I use between pages is getting lost in the middle. What can I do?

Comment: POST data is not preserved after redirect unless you use `R=307` or `R=308`